# react redux toolkit- action in dispatch returns err: Object(...) is not a function at onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I'm learning redux toolkit for reactjs. I was watching a toturial on youtube and do everything on it step by step. I write a app witch has 2 components : Profile and Login! when you click an the button of Login component, the profile info should changes. but now, when I press that button, I get this error:

*Login.js:12   Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at onClick (Login.js:12)*
I want to know what is my mistake?!

> index.js:

```
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from './futures/users'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user : userReducer
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

> src > futures > users.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: { value: { name: "", age: 0, gender: "" } },
  reducer: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { login } = userSlice.actions;
console.log(login); //it returned undefined

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

> Profile.js: (It works well)

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Profile = () => {
    const user = useSelector((state)=> state.user.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Profile</h1>
      <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
      <p>Age: {user.age}</p>
      <p>Gender: {user.gender}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

> Login.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../futures/users";

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>{
            dispatch(login({ name: "Paria", age: 21, gender: "demigirl" }));
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

and I added these components (Login and Profile) in return function of App.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[It](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) should be `reducers` (with an `s`) not `reducer`**

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: { value: { name: "", age: 0, gender: "" } },
  reducers: {  // <-- Change to `reducers` here, mate
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same error. just add '/react' for importing from query.
importing is different in react.

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query' //not use this

/* React-specific entry point that automatically generates
   hooks corresponding to the defined endpoints */
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react' //use this one
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32510255)